# Restore default tab colors on gnome terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

From one day to another (probably after some ubuntu updates and a restart), my gnome terminal tabs got this appearance:
[image: Super black tab color]

but the normal was like this (this is a image from internet, that resembles how it was):
[image: Normal dark theme tab color]

I've already tried to change the gnome shell theme and disable extensions, but it had not effect.

Does anyone know how to restore the tab colors?

UPDATE: i noticed that when the terminal is in full screen, it displays the correct tab colors:

[image: fullscreen gnome terminal tabs]

Comment: Turns out that it's a yaru-theme specific, problem. I've opened an issue on it's github.

Comment: the issue is [here](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/2481)